# How can i find php <defunct> file path?

Tags: php, linux

I have processes like that:

```
24471 myuser     17   0     0    0    0 Z  3.0  0.0   0:00.09 [php] <defunct>
24488 myuser     17   0     0    0    0 Z  3.0  0.0   0:00.09 [php] <defunct>
```

How can I find file path?

Thanks.

Comment: Peek into `/proc/24471/cmdline` or something.

Answer (score 3):

There is a symbolic link in `/proc/$PROCESSID/exe` to the executable file of a process.

Hopefully you can type

```
ls -l /proc/24471/exe
```